# Unable to set custom UITableViewCell properties in ViewController with two TableViews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In the comment controller of an app I am creating I have two tableViews: The comment table and the table that appears when trying to tag another user.

All data is loading properly, but when I attempt to create a custom cell (ExploreCell) my custom properties (the UILabel and UIImageView) are not displaying. For testing's sake I tried chaining the background colors of the cells and they do set to black.

I have registered all of the proper nibs and I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewItem cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"cellforrow");
if (tableViewItem == self.tableView) {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    CommentCell *cell = (CommentCell *)[tableViewItem dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


    if (fetched == YES) {
        [cell.usernameLabel setTitle:[[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"username"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.usernameLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.usernameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(goToUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.profilePicture setImage:[profPicDictionary objectForKey:[[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"username"]]];
    }

    [cell.commentLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.commentLabel setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [cell.commentLabel setEditable:NO];
    [cell.commentLabel setSelectable:YES];
    [cell.commentLabel setDelegate:self];
    cell.commentLabel.attributedText = [self getAttributedText:[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"comment"]];
    cell.commentLabel.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -5, 0, 0);
    [cell.commentLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.commentLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.commentLabel.frame.origin.y, 257, 10)];
    [cell.commentLabel sizeToFit];

    NSDate *createdAt = [[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"createdAt"];

    cell.createdLabel.text = [self setCreatedTimestamp:createdAt];


    [cell.usernameLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Radikal-Thin" size:14.0f]];
    [cell.commentLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Radikal-Thin" size:15.0f]];
    [cell.createdLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Radikal-Thin" size:14.0f]];

    return cell;
} else {
    NSLog(@"explore");
    static NSString *identifier = @"userCell";
    ExploreCell *tagCell = (ExploreCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!tagCell) {
        tagCell = [[ExploreCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"userCell"];
    }
    if (tableData.count >> 0) {
        [tagCell.usernameLabel setText:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"username"]];
        [tagCell.profilePicture setImage:[profPicDictionary objectForKey:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"username"]]];
        tagCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    NSLog(@"tagcell: %@",tagCell);
    return tagCell;
}
```

}

Comment: If your view controller has multiple tableViews, I'd advise against naming either of them simply `tableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the following line in else part and you should be good to go

```
ExploreCell *tagCell = (ExploreCell *)[tableViewItem dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

Change this line and let me know if you still find any problem.